# Initial Value of Dynamically-Allocated Memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

In C++, when you dynamically allocate an array of `int`, are the values of the `int`s undefined or initialized to 0?

```
    int *array = new int[50];
```

Comment: It's always just garbage; whatever was left there.

Answer (score 9):

The term is **uninitialized**. But it depends how you initialize the array. You could *value-initialize it*:

```
int *array = new int[50]();
```

and the values would be 0.

If you leave it uninitialized, you can't know what values are there because reading from them would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

If you use vectors instead of arrays, you will get an initial value of 0 for all elements:

```
std::vector<int> v(50);
```

If you want a different default value, you can specify one:

```
std::vector<int> v(50, 42);
```

An additional benefit of vectors is that you don't have to manually release the underlying array.

Comment: I always forget to suggest `vector` and whatnot :)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question no.. But there is a way to set default values.
Try:

```
int *arr = new int[SIZE]() ;
```

The above is C++ standard but may not work on all compilers. The safe bet would be to use a loop and initialize it to a default value of your choice.

```
for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  arr[i] = 1; //1 being my default value
}
```

EDIT:
As others have pointed out even better:  [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)

Comment: How does value-initialization depend on the compiler?

Comment: I tried it once on a Borland and Dev C++ compiler, the initialization never worked for Borland.

Comment: value-initialization is a standard term and initializes integral types to 0. If a compiler doesn't support it... well, it's a shitty compiler.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I tried to find an article but can't find any that says it is compiler dependent. So you may be right :)

Comment: There, I think my answer should reflect that some compilers may misbehave.

Comment: Compilers that don't support value initialization should be burnt with fire. Is it also your opinion that we should always use `new[]` instead of `std::vector` because it might not be supported? -1 for even suggesting the loop.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore 100% of compilers are shitty since none does follow standard exactly. standard does not matter in practice for developer, everything is compiler-dependent.

Comment: @ÖöTiib so should we follow all our answers by "int x = 0;" might not work on all compilers? Really? This is basic stuff.

Comment: ALthough the loop is not the best way to do things (you should use `memset`, which will use any platform dependent string instructions), this answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @LewsTherin I'm said you think that. I was merely pointing out there's stuff we as developers can take for granted. Including value-initialization. Of course compilers have glitches, but you can write code just to fend against them, especially not before you really know there is a problem with the compiler. And if there is, you should change it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore sure when you know a popular compiler where this does not work then it is nice to tell it. We compile with real compilers not with standard.

Comment: Borland and DevC++ are so old, and pre-Standard, that their output is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Can the downvoters elaborate as to how this answer is invalid in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

They will be undefined. Just garbage depending on what was in those locations before you initialized it

Answer (score 2):

If you write

```
int *array = new int[50];
```

then the values in the array can contain anything, but if you write

```
int *array = new int[50]();
```

then you will be calling the "default constructor" and everything will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

They are neighter, they contain whatever data was there before the allocation.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, allocate an object in memory means simply reserving a number of memory blocks to that object. 
The initial value is basically what was present in those blocks which is most of the time random values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assume it is garbage, even though it may often (especially in debug builds) be initialised to zero or some other predefined value indicating uninitialised memory (usually some [HexSpeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) value if zero is not used).

E.g. see http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html#table

Answer (score 0):

It is completely undefined by the standard, and really just depends on your OS and compiler. In some compilers, it just uses whatever the OS gave you, and in some OSes that will be 0s, others garbage, and others something else. Or the compiler could automatically insert an invisible `memset` after a `malloc` or `new`. But in any case, the point is, never rely on the value. Even if your current version of your compiler makes it 0s, say, that might change in a future version, and probably won't be true on another compiler.