# Access to infinite array elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I try to understand pointers. Question is: should'nt I get a segmentation fault when compiling the second for loop? If no why not? I could not prevent any access to elements which are outside of y[0][dim].

```
int main(){                                                                                                   
        int dim = 3;                                                                                          
        int ordnung = 2;                                                                                      
        double** y = new double*[ordnung];                                                                    

        for(int i = 0; i<ordnung; i++){                                                                       
                y[i] = new double[dim];                                                                       
        }                                                                                                     

        for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++){                                                                          
                cout << y[0][i] << endl;                                                                      
        }                                                                                                     

        delete[] y;                                                                                           
        return 0;                                                                                             
}
```

The output is also confusing me:

```
0
0
0
1.63042e-332
0
0
0
6.520933e-319
```

and ongoing zeros. What does that mean?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553154/initial-value-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory using `new[]`, it doesn't initialize the memory in any specific way. Its content is *indeterminate* and accessing it, even for reading, leads to *undefined behavior*.

You also go out of bounds of the allocated memory which also leads *undefined behavior*. C++ have no built-in bounds-checking.

And then you don't free all the memory you allocate. For each `new` there should be a matching `delete`, and for every `new[]` a matching `delete[]`.

---

Lastly a few notes: First of all if you ever think you need a *dynamic array*, then your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

And about the memory being uninitialized when using `new` or `new[]`, that of course depends on *what* you allocate. If you allocate an object (or an array of objects) with a constructor, that will of course cause the constructor to be called. The constructor may, or may *not*, initialize the object.

Comment: so if I work with these uninitialized elements I will always run into undefined behavior in further code so it does not make sense to use them? So I have to explicitly prevent users from accessing them?